# ContextMenuStrip in PropertyGrid

Tags: propertygrid, uitypeeditor

Top-level control cannot be added to a controlTell me please, how to show ContextMenuStrip in PropertyGrid? For this I use this code:

```
public class SaveFileNameEditor : UITypeEditor
    {
        public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
        }

        public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
        {
            IWindowsFormsEditorService FileEditor =
            provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as
             IWindowsFormsEditorService;
            ContextMenuStrip MenuList = null;
            ToolStripMenuItem MenuItem = null;
            if (FileEditor != null)
            {
                MenuList = new ContextMenuStrip ();
                MenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("Add File...");
                MenuList.Items.Add(MenuItem);
                MenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("Save File ...");
                MenuList.Items.Add(MenuItem);
                MenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("Delete File ...");
                MenuList.Items.Add(MenuItem);

                FileEditor.DropDownControl(MenuList);
                MenuList.Show();
            }
            return value;
        }    
    }
```

But I get the error message "Top-level control cannot be added to a control" on line

```
FileEditor.DropDownControl(MenuList);
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, plus it seems difficult to believe since neither FileEditor or MenuList is null. Please show some real code and a full stack frame.

Comment: Sorry, the method GetEditStype is better write like this:

Comment: public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
        }

Comment: Don't have the same error, it says "Top-level control cannot be added to a control." which is expected. PS: update your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Instead of

```
FileEditor.DropDownControl(MenuList);
```

put

```
Point MenuCoords = (System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition);
MenuList.Show(MenuCoords);
```